# How to install aMSN on Scientific Linux?

Tags: software-installation, scientific-linux, chat

I can't find aMSN in the Scientific Linux 6 repositories.. How can I install it?

Comment: Let me ask if you want to be more flexible with your question... what about installing another MSN client such as Pidgin or Kmess? I think that it could work for you but nobody can answer that to your question, since it is about aMSN and not any MSN client.

Comment: [root@a ~]# yum search kmess
Warning: No matches found for: kmess
No Matches found
[root@a ~]# 

AND

http://developer.pidgin.im/ticket/13298

Comment: I cannot understand why the pidgin ticket link, but anyway, have you tried with http://www.amsn-project.net/linux-downloads.php?

If not, try downloading the Fedora package (it's RPM) or the source code.

Comment: p.s.: I get this message when I try to add a buddy on MSN with pidgin...: http://i.imgur.com/qXy0K.png

Comment: so pidgin has a bug..

Comment: @LanceBaynes If you have decided to install Pidgin and experience problems with Pidgin, please do not post them here. This question page should only be concerned with your original problem.

Comment: How to install aMSN on Scientific Linux?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well if there's no packaged binary for your distro you can try building the package from [source](http://www.amsn-project.net/linux-downloads.php#tarball). Get the gzipped tarball and extract it somewhere you do your build-related stuff, and follow the standard procedure:

```
$ cd ~/build
$ tar xzf amsn-0.98.4-src.tar.gz
$ cd amsn-0.98.4
```

Here you make sure to read all important files, such as `README`, `INSTALL` and `HELP` before continuing. Then you compile and install:

```
$ ./configure
$ make
# make install
```

**Note**: on `SL 6.1 64bit` you will need this before the install:

```
# yum install gcc-c++ tcl-devel tk-devel libpng-devel libjpeg-devel gstreamer-devel farsight2-devel -y
```

Comment: yum install gcc-c++ helped!!

Answer (score 2):

I just googled for "amsn el6 rpm" and got tons of hits. So you can download an already built rpm and install it.

el6 is short for RedHat Enterprise Linux 6 - which is the "orignal" OS for the binary compatible clones (CentOS 6, Scientific Linux 6).

Comment: As I said, the RPM should be the first choice instead of building